# Hide section numbering, but keep labeling

Tags: sectioning

How do I hide section and subsection numbers while keeping labels for referencing? I have tried renewing `\thesubection` as follows but that leaves a blank space when referencing a section using \ref.

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{}
```

Example usage

```
 In section \ref{obj}, we explain ...
```

Later

```
 \section{Objective} \label{obj}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes no sense, but journal editors sometimes have weird ideas. How is a reader supposed to understand what “section 2” refers to? Well, ask that journal editor.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% \@seccntformat is the command that adds the number to section titles
% we make it a no-op
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In section \ref{obj}, we explain \dots

\section{Objective}\label{obj}
Here we do the work.

\end{document}
```

[image]

It would be possible to remove section numbers, while keeping them in subsections, if you need so.

Answer (score 4):

### Referencing by name/title

Without section numbers, it does not make much sense to refer sections by number. There are alternatives:

- Package `nameref`, which provides `\nameref`.
- Package `titleref`, which provides `\titleref`.

Both can be used to reference the section by name (= title).

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{nameref}% references by name

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}% disables section numbering

\begin{document}

  \noindent
  In section \enquote{\nameref{obj}}, we explain \dots

  \section{Objective}
  \label{obj}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Referencing by "time"

If section names are forbidden, then other wording can be used, e.g.:

```
In the first/previous/next/last section, we explain
```

or just

```
Later we explain
```

Comment: I agree it does not make sense. The journal editor wants it that way, so I need something that works even if is not a good solution. Unfortunately, referencing by name looks odd for a journal paper.

Comment: If there is no section number, how is the reader supposed to find the section? Something like "In the first|previous|next|last" section remains to avoid non-existent section numbers.